# Building a software that listens to database changes and calls up other methods. Am I doing right architecture?

Tags: java, mysql, design-patterns

I am a 2 months old software engineer. I have got a software piece to be rewritten in Java. I have no experience in writing industry standard code or designing applications according to standards. So, this is a chance for me to do that!

This is my requirement-I need to write a program that listens to a MySQL database for new entries. If the number of new entries reach a threshold, the listener should call a class to pull the data from the database and to do some operations on this data.

I read about design patterns in Java and came to know about Observer pattern. Do you think I can go ahead with this or I can simply write a piece of code to do the listening and don't care much about the patterns.

Please let me know your inputs. I understand that experience has a lot to do in this space.

Thanks

Comment: I think that this question will be closed as opinion based. If you take 10 randomly selected users from StackOverflow with Java knowledge you will get 10 different solutions...

Comment: In my oppinion you shouldn't use the observer pattern. The observer pattern observes the state of an object in your application. It is not intendend to observe your database tables. It would be a kind of abusing this pattern. My recommendation is to write a batch job which checks the database table every amount of time. I think I would do a polling mechanism.

Comment: Here we see, Uwe Plonus is totally right with his presumption. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs :) Dear @user2519837, we have a batch operation in place already. Let me anyway discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a design pattern is better design approach if the intent is correctly matched. i.e. if design pattern is used for the right intent. It helps achieve the design goal of decoupling.

Observer pattern is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems. The Observer pattern is also a key part in the familiar model–view–controller (MVC) architectural pattern.

Looks like a perfect fit to me for your problem.